# How do I eliminate people from a search because of a code

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a more complex situation but I think I can make the example easier to answer. Let's say I am trying to query people who are in TX and only drive blue trucks. I am using an Oracle database.

I have 2 tables (`State table`) and (`Truck table`)
They join on the persons ID #

The Auto table is huge! This is the biggest problem because I do not want to get a query hung or to run for very long.

**State Table**

```
 People     State
 ------     -----
 111        TX  
 222        TX  
 333        CA
```

**Truck Table**

```
 People     Date     Color
 ------     ----     ------
 111        1995     Orange
 111        1996     Blue
 111        1997     White
 111        2017     Blue
 111        2017     Gold
 222        2006     Blue
 333        2007     Blue
```

What I want to return is only 222 because they did not have any other color of truck.

```
 222       2006     Blue
```

If there is a better way to create something that looks like a table I would like to know that also.

Comment: Why only 222? Why not 333 also? Then: What role does the State table play in all of this? How about the Date column from the Truck table? If they play no role, then say so (or even better, don't even include them in the question).

Comment: @mathguy, 333 is not in TX.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - Oh, OK, I missed that in the problem statement. I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `Auto` table?

Comment: Be more specific about "only drive blue trucks." If they have more than one truck, does that count or not? Bottom line, should person 111 also be included in your results?

Comment: @SandPiper, the specification says the result should *not* return 111 - "because they did not have any other color of truck".

Comment: Not clear: do you want to return `222`, or do you want to return the full row (or rows!) including `date` and `color`? (Obviously returning `color` is redundant given the problem requirement, but not so clear regarding `date`.)

Comment: Hope this helps. I do want the answer to be all three values "222",       "2006",     "Blue", and it would not hurt if I could add "TX" from the State table but I do not have to have it. I do not know if there are any Null Values or not. I see several ways to do it listed. Thank you everyone, but can I ask which is the way that will use the least resources. Lets say the Truck table has 6 million records. I do not want to double the query run time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

how about using having.

```
select state.people, state,  color, count(color)
from state, truck
where state.people = truck.people
and state.state = 'TX'
and color = 'Blue'
group by state.people, state, color
having count(color) = 1
```

here is the fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89bdc/14

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the columns have NOT NULL constraints:

```
select State.People
from State
join Truck on Truck.People = State.People
where State.State = 'TX'
and Truck.Color = 'Blue'
and not exists (
  select null
  from Truck t2
  where t2.People = Truck.People
  and t2.Color != 'Blue'
);
```

A covering index on `Truck (People, Color)` would probably suffice for performance.

An alternative to consider:

```
select State.People
from State
join Truck on Truck.People = State.People
where State.State = 'TX'
and Truck.Color = 'Blue'
minus
select Truck.People
from Truck
where Truck.People = Truck.People
and Truck.Color != 'Blue';
```

For more performance tuning I would start by looking at the execution plans and approximate data volumes.

Answer (score 0):

**ADDED** (after the fact): The solution below returns only the `people` identifier (222 in this case), not the row (or rows!) from the `truck` table for those people. If you need the full rows, instead of an aggregate query, you can use analytic functions. Easy to modify, but first answer the question I asked in a Comment under the original question.   END EDIT.

```
with
  state_table ( people, state ) as (
    select 111, 'TX' from dual union all  
    select 222, 'TX' from dual union all  
    select 333, 'CA' from dual
  ),
  truck_table ( people, dt, color ) as (
    select 111, 1995, 'Orange' from dual union all
    select 111, 1996, 'Blue'   from dual union all
    select 111, 1997, 'White'  from dual union all
    select 111, 2017, 'Blue'   from dual union all
    select 111, 2017, 'Gold'   from dual union all
    select 222, 2006, 'Blue'   from dual union all
    select 333, 2007, 'Blue'   from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names
select people
from   truck_table
where  people in ( select people
                   from   state_table
                   where  state = 'TX'
                 )
group by people
having count(case when color != 'Blue' or color is null then 1 end) = 0
;

    PEOPLE
----------
       222
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying a sub query as below:

```
select * from (select state.People, truck.Date, truck.Color, 
count(truck.People) over (partition by state.People) Cnt from state
left join truck on state.People = truck.People and truck.Color = 'Blue'
where state.State = 'TX')
where cnt = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start by querying the tables using a JOIN:

```
SELECT People, Date, Color
  FROM Truck 
    INNER JOIN State ON Truck.People = State.People
  WHERE State.State = 'TX'
    AND Truck.Color = 'Blue'
```

If performance of the query is insufficient, then you may want to add appropriate indexes on either table.  For instance, you may want to add an index to the Truck table on the Color attribute.

Comment: This would incorrectly return 111 (111 doesn't *only* drive Blue trucks)

Comment: Depends on how you interpret ONLY. OP needs to clarify expected result set.